# Optical mouse sensor M116504386 arduino libary

Tags: sensors, mouse

I am doing project and I used optical mouse IC sensor M116504386 with 16 pins and I don't know how to get this sensor libraries to interface it with arduino uno.

Comment: When I google "M116504386", I get 2 results in Chinese. Is this the sensor you are using? https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/12907 Can you tell us which library you're using?

Comment: do you still have the mouse? ... if you have it, try to determine the schematic diagram of the mouse